# Obtaining YCSB results

Tags: java, ycsb

I get text files with many details as the output of an YCSB experiment. Those are like the following example:

```
  Client config file: client_config
Client class name: eventualConsistency_client.EventualClient
[OVERALL], RunTime(ms), 2157
[OVERALL], Throughput(ops/sec), 46.36068613815485
[TOTAL_GCS_PS_Scavenge], Count, 1
[TOTAL_GC_TIME_PS_Scavenge], Time(ms), 15
[TOTAL_GC_TIME_%_PS_Scavenge], Time(%), 0.6954102920723227
[TOTAL_GCS_PS_MarkSweep], Count, 0
[TOTAL_GC_TIME_PS_MarkSweep], Time(ms), 0
[TOTAL_GC_TIME_%_PS_MarkSweep], Time(%), 0.0
[TOTAL_GCs], Count, 1
[TOTAL_GC_TIME], Time(ms), 15
[TOTAL_GC_TIME_%], Time(%), 0.6954102920723227
[CLEANUP], Operations, 1
[CLEANUP], AverageLatency(us), 7.0
[CLEANUP], MinLatency(us), 7
[CLEANUP], MaxLatency(us), 7
[CLEANUP], 95thPercentileLatency(us), 7
[CLEANUP], 99thPercentileLatency(us), 7
[CLEANUP], 7, 1.0
[INSERT], Operations, 100
[INSERT], AverageLatency(us), 7932.67
[INSERT], MinLatency(us), 1618
[INSERT], MaxLatency(us), 203903
[INSERT], 95thPercentileLatency(us), 9063
[INSERT], 99thPercentileLatency(us), 14543
[INSERT], 1618, 1.0
[INSERT], 2117, 1.0
[INSERT], 2439, 1.0
[INSERT], 2455, 1.0
[INSERT], 2587, 1.0
[INSERT], 2635, 1.0
[INSERT], 2687, 1.0
[INSERT], 2709, 1.0
[INSERT], 2741, 1.0
[INSERT], 2809, 1.0
[INSERT], 2833, 1.0
[INSERT], 2855, 1.0
[INSERT], 2887, 1.0
[INSERT], 2947, 1.0
[INSERT], 2963, 1.0
[INSERT], 2991, 1.0
[INSERT], 3103, 1.0
[INSERT], 3161, 1.0
[INSERT], 3175, 1.0
[INSERT], 3217, 1.0
[INSERT], 3837, 1.0
[INSERT], 3845, 1.0
[INSERT], 4303, 1.0
[INSERT], 4335, 1.0
[INSERT], 4495, 1.0
[INSERT], 4739, 1.0
[INSERT], 4831, 1.0
[INSERT], 5627, 1.0
[INSERT], 5655, 1.0
[INSERT], 5707, 1.0
[INSERT], 5919, 1.0
[INSERT], 5927, 1.0
[INSERT], 5963, 1.0
[INSERT], 5979, 1.0
[INSERT], 6043, 1.0
[INSERT], 6047, 1.0
[INSERT], 6099, 1.0
[INSERT], 6103, 2.0
[INSERT], 6135, 1.0
[INSERT], 6139, 1.0
[INSERT], 6143, 1.0
[INSERT], 6151, 1.0
[INSERT], 6155, 1.0
[INSERT], 6163, 1.0
[INSERT], 6167, 2.0
[INSERT], 6219, 1.0
[INSERT], 6223, 1.0
[INSERT], 6283, 1.0
[INSERT], 6287, 1.0
[INSERT], 6303, 1.0
[INSERT], 6371, 1.0
[INSERT], 6375, 1.0
[INSERT], 6383, 1.0
[INSERT], 6407, 1.0
[INSERT], 6415, 1.0
[INSERT], 6439, 1.0
[INSERT], 6459, 1.0
[INSERT], 6467, 1.0
[INSERT], 6563, 2.0
[INSERT], 6583, 1.0
[INSERT], 6615, 1.0
[INSERT], 6631, 1.0
[INSERT], 6643, 1.0
[INSERT], 6647, 1.0
[INSERT], 6699, 1.0
[INSERT], 6731, 1.0
[INSERT], 6779, 1.0
[INSERT], 6791, 2.0
[INSERT], 6815, 1.0
[INSERT], 6823, 1.0
[INSERT], 6875, 1.0
[INSERT], 6879, 1.0
[INSERT], 6883, 1.0
[INSERT], 6923, 1.0
[INSERT], 6931, 1.0
[INSERT], 6947, 1.0
[INSERT], 6971, 1.0
[INSERT], 7015, 1.0
[INSERT], 7035, 1.0
[INSERT], 7059, 1.0
[INSERT], 7239, 1.0
[INSERT], 7555, 1.0
[INSERT], 7683, 1.0
[INSERT], 7759, 1.0
[INSERT], 7835, 1.0
[INSERT], 7943, 1.0
[INSERT], 8123, 1.0
[INSERT], 8155, 1.0
[INSERT], 8335, 1.0
[INSERT], 8935, 1.0
[INSERT], 9063, 1.0
[INSERT], 9655, 1.0
[INSERT], 12151, 1.0
[INSERT], 13015, 1.0
[INSERT], 14543, 1.0
[INSERT], 203903, 1.0
```

I want to get results such as Throughput, latency, etc. I was thinking to search the text file. For example I search "[OVERALL], Throughput(ops/sec), " and then I take anything after , and before new line.

But isn't any way other than parsing the text file?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to do with those numbers, it could be a simple python/perl  script.

You could also sample the output to file and create graphs. do read - https://github.com/brianfrankcooper/YCSB/wiki/Core-Properties